# Upgrading Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Following is the reminder I am getting for my facebook app:

'Application-name' currently has access to Graph API v2.1 which will reach the end of its 2-year lifetime on 30 October, 2016. To ensure a smooth transition, please migrate all calls to Graph API v2.2 or higher.
To check if your app will be affected by this upgrade you can use the Version Upgrade Tool. This will show you which calls, if any, are affected by this change as well as any replacement calls in newer versions. If you do not see any calls, your app may not be affected by this change.
You can also use our changelog to see the full list of changes in all Graph API versions.

I have changed the version to v2.2 from the code level. But from Facebook application dashboard, how to upgrade the version? In Dashboard advance settings tab, there is an option to upgrade api which says force all calls to v2.2 or higher version. Should that be done? I don't want it to make calls to version higher than v2.2.

Comment: See my answer for this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/42506649/3222336

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the version flag to your API calls or just wait until v2.1 is deprecated - your App will be upgraded to v2.2 automatically.

Comment: It won't get upgraded to anything higher than v2.2. Right?

Comment: exactly, it will just upgrade to the last version that is not removed

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Have a version flag too in my api call.